# Difference between SSL pinning and certificate validating

Tags: ios, ssl, https, self-signed, pinning

Can someone explain the difference between validating a certificate like described with a self-signed certificate here:

https://jetforme.org/2013/05/validating-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-ios-and-os-x-against-a-changing-host-name/

and SSL pinning like described here:

https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning

- What does `SecPolicyCreateSSL` means?
- What in detail is `SecTrustEvaluate` doing?
- Is the procedure in the first link including SSL pinning?
- If not, is it a good idea to implement both?

Thanks

Comment: SecPolicyCreateSSL is a Policy object which is used to evaluate the SSL Certificate Chains.

SecTrustEvaluate is a function which evaluate the trust for the specified SSL certificate and the Policies.

Comment: okay, thank's for your answer but that's derivable from the function name. What's the difference of SecPolicyCreateSSL() and SecPolicyCreateBasicX509() for example?

Comment: The code in the first link has a huge security issue (calling SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, NULL) to disable hostname validation, the step 2 described in my answer).

Comment: I know. But it's the only way for validating self-signed certificates, right?

Comment: True but I would still self-sign the certificate for the right name, so I don't have to disable a crucial security feature (which may not matter here but people copy & paste code).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First let's clarify the terminology in the Cocoa world:

- A `SecPolicyRef` is a policy that defines the rules when validating a certificate chain: the things to check for in the certificates within the chain (signature, expiration date, etc.), which determine whether the certificate chain is valid/trusted or not.
- A `SecTrustRef` object is the combination of a certificate chain (basically an array of `SecCertificateRef`) and a `SecPolicyRef`. This object represents all the things needed to validate a certificate chain (the certificates + the policy).

Validating a server's certificate chain involves two steps:

1. The certificate path needs to be validated (the signatures, the expiration date, etc.) to ensure that the server certificate was issued by a trusted CA.
2. The name for which the server certificate was issued (Common Name or Subject Alternative Name) needs to match the name of the server the App is trying to connect to.

These steps are expressed by a `SecPolicyRef`:

- `SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()` returns a policy that has all the things to check for **1**; this is there for historical reasons but it should never be used.
- `SecPolicyCreateSSL()` returns a policy that has all the rules for both **1 and 2**; this is the one you must use.

You then use `SecTrustEvaluate()` to validate the server's `SecTrustRef`. The result will tell you if the server's certificate chain is trusted based on the `SecPolicyRef` that was passed.

Lastly, SSL pinning means adding a third step to this whole process:

3. The certificate chain must contain a specific key or certificate. This ensures that only the certificate you know you deployed on your servers will be accepted by the App, instead of any certificate issued by any CA for your domain.

I would advise against writing your own implementation of SSL validation (with or without pinning) as, you can tell, the APIs are extremely complex and there is a big potential for huge mistakes that would make your extremely App insecure.

I have worked on a library to make it easy to do SSL pinning; it's available at https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit and takes care of all the heavy lifting.